# Template class assignment operator class

Tags: c++, templates, assignment-operator

I have a TemplateArray and a CharArray class.

How do I make it so the templatearray's assignment operator only copies in from the chararray class when the templatearray is of the same type (I.E. char) or similar type (I.E. unsigned char) to chararray?

TemplateArray and CharArray are functionally the same (except CharArray can handle NULL terminated strings).

For example:

```
template<typename TemplateItem>
TemplateList & TemplateList<TemplateItem>::operator=(const CharArray &ItemCopy)
{
    //How do I only copy when TemplateList is of type char (or similar unsigned char)
    //IE is same/similar to CharArray
    //Both classes are functionally the same, except CharArray is chars only
}
```

Comment: A code example is worth 1000 words ;)

Comment: Okay. I can't copy and paste from the many header files, but I'll quote the function line.

Comment: I think you can only do it by template specialization for a "char"..otherwise you will have to find a way for runtime type identification by implementing a reflection or some other kind of mechanism..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need a specialization of `TemplateList::operator=`:

```
template<>
TemplateList& TemplateList<char>::operator=(const CharArray &ItemCopy)
{
    // Do the copying here, you don't provide enough
    // information for a practical suggestion
}
```