# How do I externalise the conversion operator?

Tags: c++, class

How do I make it so the following code is externalised outside the class:

```
template<typename TemplateItem>
class TestA
{
     operator const int (){return 10;}
};
```

So it appears like:

```
template<typename TemplateItem>
class TestA
{
    operator const int ();
};

template<>
TestA<int>::operator const int()
{
    //etc etc
}
```

So I can specialise the function for different templated types?

Comment: Is there something missing from your question? If not, the answer is "just like you have there."  Is there some reason you don't do exactly what you've described? (Well, except for a missing `public:`).

Comment: @rob: If it is how I've precisely written it, then that's fine (I just wasn't know what the correct way of writing it is). Be aware specialisation is involved, so I am not sure if that impacts it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write this:

```
template <typename T> class TestA
{
  operator const int();
};

template <typename T> TestA<T>::operator const int()
{
  return 10;
}
```

The standard antonym of "inline" is usually "out of line", by the way. Also, I'd probably make the function `const`, as one usually does with conversion operators (to allow conversions from constant objects).

You can either specialize the entire class, or just the member function. For the member function only, write this:

```
template <> TestA<int>::operator const int() { /* ... */ }
```

For the entire class specialization, the syntax is this:

```
template <> class TestA<int>
{
  operator const int();
};
TestA<int>::operator const int() { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Though you answer his direction question, his intent is to specialize which can't be done _quite_ this easy.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks, I missed that. Updated.

Comment: @MooingDuck & Kerrek - I *think* I understand what you are saying, but why does [this](http://ideone.com/DaTAC) compile and run?

Comment: @Rob: I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377585/template-class-assignment-operator-class) answer as the basis for the specialisation. Just I didn't know if it worked with conversion or not.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Alright, I'm confused.  http://codepad.org/9GQ3mEV5  Codepad seems to let me do exactly what he wants.  MSVC10 as well.

Comment: @SSight3 : As both of the posted answers are currently wrong, I would hold off on marking one as an answer if I were you. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: what's your objection to this answer?

Comment: @Kerrek : "*You can only specialize the entire class, not any particular member function*" is incorrect.

Comment: @ildjarn: I think I got confused about this one before. Fixing it now! I'm wondering now what it was about members that cannot be specialized...

Comment: @Kerrek : My answer has the relevant standardese if you need it :-P

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, thanks, it's good to see the relevant quotes. I shall keep that in mind!

Comment: @Kerrek : You may have been thinking of member templates -- member templates cannot be specialized without also specializing the outer primary template.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can specialize a non-template function of a template class without specializing the whole class.  Which means you have to cheat.  Simplist way is to move most of the implementation to a "Base" class, (everything that the two share), and have TestA inherit from that base class, and only define the functions that need specializing.

```
 //general base
template<typename TemplateItem>
class TestABase
{
protected:
    TemplateItem data;
};
//non specialized members
template<typename TemplateItem>
class TestA: public TestABase<TemplateItem>
{
public:
    operator const int ();
};
//specialized members
template<>
class TestA<int> : public TestABase<TemplateItem>
{
public:
    operator const int ();
};


//implementations
template<typename TemplateItem>
TestA<TemplateItem>::operator const int()
{
   return data;
}
template<>
TestA<int>::operator const int()
{
   return data;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, fair point. I hadn't included a templateitem for simplicity, but there is one in the original main class. I had tacked on the template part as a side thought as I wanted it to be understood it was for specialisation rather than a general function.

Answer (score 1):

First off, declare and define the primary templates as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class TestA
{
public:
    operator int() const;
};

template<typename T>
TestA<T>::operator int() const
{
    return -1;
}
```

Regarding specialization, the C++03 standard §14.5.1.1/1 tells us that non-template member functions (and constructors!) of a class template are themselves considered function templates:

> A member function of a class template may be defined outside of the class template definition in which it is declared. [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> class Array {
>     T* v;
>     int sz;
> public:
>     explicit Array(int);
>     T& operator[](int);
>     T& elem(int i) { return v[i]; }
>     // ...
> };
> ```
>
> declares three function templates. The subscript function might be defined like this:
>
> ```
> template<class T> T& Array<T>::operator[](int i)
> {
>     if (i<0 || sz<=i) error("Array: range error");
>     return v[i];
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example*]

Consequently, they can be specialized *without* also specializing the rest of the primary class template (unlike if you were to specialize, explicitly or partially, the class template itself):

```
template<>
TestA<int>::operator int() const
{
    return 5;
}

template<>
TestA<double>::operator int() const
{
    return 3;
}
```

**[Full demo](http://ideone.com/dEXNZ)**